# How do I let pip to know to remove the systemd service file

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

In my python package I offer the user to run as a service and then install a .service file.

Is there a way to let pip know to remove it if the package is uninstalled ?

Thank you

Comment: If your project (library, application) offers a service to install additional files, it should also offer a service to uninstall them. In general, no this is not something that is done as part of Python packaging. But there are probably ways to do so, and as far as I know they are all bad practice and deprecated. For you own curiosity you could look up `distutils data_files`, also [this](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#non-package-data-files). -- Use system-level packaging tools (rpm/apt, deb/yum, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` is not a full blown package manager, even less system package manager. It doesn't support post-install or pre-uninstall scripts.

The 2 solutions for your problems are:

1. Include said `service` file in your wheels so `pip uninstall` removes it;
2. Do not use `pip` at all, convert your package to [rpm](https://pypi.org/project/pyp2rpm/) or [deb](https://pypi.org/project/stdeb/).

Comment: I will look into packaging / hosting system level packages then. Thanks